# Compile gradle subproject with another subproject as a dependency

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have two projects:

```
workspace
 Project1
  |--build.gradle
  |--settings.gradle
  |--Subproject1
  |    |--build.gradle
  |--Subproject2
  |    |--build.gradle

 Project 2
  |--build.gradle
  |--settings.gradle
  |--Subproject2-1
  |    |--build.gradle
```

`Subproject1` have as a dependency a `subproject2` and `Subproject2-1` need `subproject1`, How can I do to `subproject2-1` have as a dependency `subproject1`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `Project2/settings.gradle` use:

```
include ':Suproject2-1'
include ':MySub1'
project(':MySub1').projectDir = new new File('/Users/foo/workspace/xxx/Project1/Subproject1')
```

Then in your `Subproject2-1/build.gradle` use:

```
dependencies {
  compile project(':MySub1')
}
```